# Do you need to include subwebs in warmup scripts

Tags: 2010, warm-up

When warming up SharePoint in the morning do you need to hit subwebs or just the root site collection(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you don't need to include sub-webs and also you don't need to include all of web applications as long as they are sharing same application pool.

**Edit**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358377/sharepoint-site-takes-a-while-to-load-first-thing-in-the-morning

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298917/best-ways-to-improve-sharepoint-2007-performance?rq=1

I went through hundred of discussion's ages ago when I was developing a timer job, but I couldn't find what exactly was the reason behind slow performance but triggering root site collection solved issues with my production server, so my answer is based on experience not discussions, there ain't any written evidence I could find so far either.

However if your farm got thousands of sites, would you going to create a timer job which will call them all ?

**Definitely not!**.

Comment: We have 4 site collections in one web application and it seems that each site collection likes to be warmed up individually

Comment: My answer is based on medium size farm with ten's of web application and hundred of site collections but since your farm looks small then you warming up all sites in morning shouldn't cause any harm, but I don't see any point of it as you need to warm-up application pools not site collections :)

Comment: yes i agree with that. seems strange

Comment: Done a little more testing, and if i warm up one site collection that lives in the same app pool as the others, only that specific site is completely warmed up. Although, the other site collection roots don't take as long as a cold build they are not as quick as when they have been visited once. So it would seem there is merit in hitting at least the root site in a site collection, and possibly all sites (maybe not so good in large environments)

Comment: So based on dmce's findings, it sounds like you should warm up sites (SPWebs)

Comment: Would be nice if findings will be supported by evidence, as far as I know its related to application pool not SPWeb cache as some people say. what kind of cache do WFE server needs everyday for each site and web site.

Answer (score 2):

We are using the famous warm up script from codeplex:

**http://spwakeup.codeplex.com/**

It helps a lot and you can specify whatever you want to wake up / warm up.

Give it a try!